# save and reload page issues vb.net/asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 buttons, one cancels, one applies the changes and one saves/exits.  The Cancel and the Save/Exit work fine, but the Apply and reload page fails.  When the apply/reload is clicked it loads the unchanged version or the template depending on which way I have tried, instead of showing the updated page.  I know this should be a fairly simple thing and have no problems in other languages when I try this, I have left a few of the options I have tried in the code as commented out parts.  I went ahead and included the whole class, but the problem area is in the btnApply_Click

```
Public Class create_worksheet
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public Property editID As Integer
Public Property TemplateID As Integer
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    editID = Request.QueryString("id")
    TemplateID = Request.QueryString("template")
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        If (Not editID = Nothing And Not editID = 0) Then

            Dim d As New Data.LINQ.LINQWorkflowDAO
            Dim wf = d.GetDefaultWorkflow(editID)
            If wf.ID > 0 Then
                litHeading.Text = "Edit Workflow"
                lblWorkflowBreadCrumb.Text = wf.Name
                txtWorksheetName.Value = wf.Name
                txtProcessDoc.Value = wf.DetailedProcessDocumentLink

                rptPrepTasks.DataSource = wf.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Prep-work")
                rptPrepTasks.DataBind()

                rptMigrationTasks.DataSource = wf.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Migration")
                rptMigrationTasks.DataBind()

                rptPostTasks.DataSource = wf.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Post-migration")
                rptPostTasks.DataBind()

                divProcessDoc.Visible = False
            Else
                If Not TemplateID = Nothing Then

                    lblWorkflowBreadCrumb.Text = "Create Workflow"
                    editID = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf Not TemplateID = Nothing Then
            Dim d2 As New Data.LINQ.LINQWorkflowDAO
            Dim wf2 = d2.GetDefaultWorkflow(TemplateID)
            If wf2.ID > 0 Then
                litHeading.Text = "Edit Workflow"

                txtProcessDoc.Value = wf2.DetailedProcessDocumentLink

                rptPrepTasks.DataSource = wf2.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Prep-work")
                rptPrepTasks.DataBind()

                rptMigrationTasks.DataSource = wf2.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Migration")
                rptMigrationTasks.DataBind()

                rptPostTasks.DataSource = wf2.Tasks.Where(Function(p) p.Type = "Post-migration")
                rptPostTasks.DataBind()

                divProcessDoc.Visible = False
            End If
            If Not TemplateID = Nothing Then

                lblWorkflowBreadCrumb.Text = "Create Workflow"
                editID = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(Request.QueryString("Action")) Then lblStatus.Text = "Workflow Saved"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If txtWorksheetName.Value.Length > 0 Then
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Data.WorkflowTask)

        Dim prepTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtPrepTitle")
        Dim migrationTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtMigrationTitle")
        Dim postTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtPostTitle")
        If Not IsNothing(prepTitles) Then
            'prep
            For i As Integer = 0 To prepTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = prepTitles(i), .Type = "Prep-work"})
            Next
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(migrationTitles) Then
            'migration
            For i As Integer = 0 To migrationTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = migrationTitles(i), .Type = "Migration"})
            Next
        End If
        'post
        If Not IsNothing(postTitles) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To postTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = postTitles(i), .Type = "Post-migration"})
            Next
        End If
        Dim d As New Data.LINQ.LINQWorkflowDAO
        Dim newid As Integer = 0
        'if this is a new process, create new, else, update existing
        If editID = Nothing Then
            d.CreateDefaultWorkflow(txtWorksheetName.Value, tasks, txtProcessDoc.Value)
        Else
            newid = d.UpdateDefaultWorkflow(editID, txtWorksheetName.Value, tasks)
        End If
        lblStatus.Text = "Workflow Saved"

        Dim wf = d.GetDefaultWorkflow(txtWorksheetName.Value)
        'Response.Redirect("create-worksheet.aspx?id=" & wf.ID.ToString() & "&action=Saved")
        Response.Redirect("default-worksheets.aspx")
    Else

        lblStatus.Text = "Please Enter a Name for the Workflow"
    End If


End Sub
Private Sub btnApply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApply.Click
    If txtWorksheetName.Value.Length > 0 Then
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Data.WorkflowTask)

        Dim prepTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtPrepTitle")
        Dim migrationTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtMigrationTitle")
        Dim postTitles = Request.Form.GetValues("txtPostTitle")
        If Not IsNothing(prepTitles) Then
            'prep
            For i As Integer = 0 To prepTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = prepTitles(i), .Type = "Prep-work"})
            Next
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(migrationTitles) Then
            'migration
            For i As Integer = 0 To migrationTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = migrationTitles(i), .Type = "Migration"})
            Next
        End If
        'post
        If Not IsNothing(postTitles) Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To postTitles.Length - 1
                tasks.Add(New Data.WorkflowTask With {.Name = postTitles(i), .Type = "Post-migration"})
            Next
        End If
        Dim d As New Data.LINQ.LINQWorkflowDAO
        Dim newid As Integer = 0
        'if this is a new process, create new, else, update existing
        If editID = Nothing Then
            d.CreateDefaultWorkflow(txtWorksheetName.Value, tasks, txtProcessDoc.Value)
        Else
            newid = d.UpdateDefaultWorkflow(editID, txtWorksheetName.Value, tasks)
        End If
        lblStatus.Text = "Workflow Saved"

        Dim wf = d.GetDefaultWorkflow(txtWorksheetName.Value)
 'testing/issue items below
        Dim originThing = d.GetDefaultWorkflow(txtWorksheetName.Value)

        'Server.Transfer(Request.Path)

        'Response.Redirect("default-worksheets.aspx")
        ' Response.Redirect("create-worksheet.aspx?id=" & originThing.ID.ToString() & "&action=Saved")
        'Response.Redirect("create-worksheet.aspx?id=" & wf.ID.ToString() & "&action=Saved")
        'Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
        'Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)
        'Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, False)
        'Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, True)

    Else

        lblStatus.Text = "Please Enter a Name for the Workflow"
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you all in advance for any direction you can give, it is appreciated

SOLVED IT!!!
Response.Redirect("create-worksheet.aspx?id=" & newid)
what the issue was the code was assigning a new id, and i kept going back to the old one.....

Comment: what is the problem? you have not said what the problem is

Comment: "Apply and reload page fails. When the apply/reload is clicked it loads the unchanged version or the template" instead of saving the changes and reloading the page.

Comment: solved the issue, updated original post.